# Как можно записать коллекцию в файл?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String s;
    String s2;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\qq.txt"));
    s = input.nextLine();
    s2 = input.nextLine();

    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(s.split(""));
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(s2.split(""));
    Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    result.addAll(l1);
    result.addAll(l2);
    result.retainAll(l1);
    result.retainAll(l2);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Вот код на Java. Он выводит результат в программу, как можно сделать, чтобы вывод осуществлялся в .txt?

Comment: Алгоритм очень простой: 1. узнать, как записывать текст в файл. 2. Применить знания на практике. Ничего сложного.

Comment: Как текст он не хотел записываться

Comment: Так и писал "не хочу записываться как текст"?

Comment: ошибку IDE выдавал

Comment: Ошибки читать не приучен? Тяжело придётся...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените `System.out.println(result);` на следующий код и вы получите аналогичный вывод в файл *out.txt* вместо консоли:

```
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\out.txt")) {
            writer.write(result.toString());
            writer.flush();
        }
```

Если вам нужно вывести элементы коллекции в файл построчно, воспользуйтесь циклом:

```
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\out.txt")) {
            for (String s : set)
                writer.write(s + '\n');
            writer.flush();
        }
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы предыдущие строки не стирались из файла?

Comment: @Дремин если вы по каждой элементарной задаче будете спрашивать у других, вместо того, чтобы попытаться найти решение самостоятельно, то лучше сразу бросить программирование и не тратить свое время. На этот вопрос есть пример 100500 страниц примеров.

Comment: @Дремин, при создании объекта FileWriter добавьте вторым параметром true. Будет: `new FileWriter("C:\\out.txt", true)`